# I have a problem with file reading/writing inside of a "for" loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I am trying to setup a folder with different files whenever the script is executed.
The script cannot be executed if the folder already exist.

When I execute the script, an async function is called and one part of this function cause a problem...

Here is my code :

```
      // I want to setup a sub folder with 6 json files     

      for(i = 1; i < 7; i++) {  // I repeat the operation 6 times

        await fs.mkdir(`./data/${member.id}/team/${i}.json`, (err) => console.log(err)); // I create the file
        let teamMember = new jsoning(`./data/${member.id}/team/${i}.json`); // I initiate the file with jsoning

        // and then I write things inside
        teamMember.set(`pokemon`, "");
        teamMember.set(`nickname`, "");
        teamMember.set(`shiny`, "");
        teamMember.set(`hasMultipleForms`, "");
        teamMember.set(`formList`, "");
        teamMember.set(`form`, "");
        teamMember.set(`ability`, "");
        teamMember.set(`baseStats`, "");
        teamMember.set(`currentStats`, "");
        teamMember.set(`evs`, "");
        teamMember.set(`ivs`, "");
        teamMember.set(`moves`, "");
        teamMember.set(`movesPP`, "");
        teamMember.set(`heldItem`, "");
        teamMember.set(`currentHps`, "");
        teamMember.set(`statusEffect`, "");

      }
```

But it returns an error :

> (node:16144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
> open 'C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\PokéBot\data\533791662628143106\team\1.json'
> at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
> at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1524:35)
> errno: -4058,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'mkdir',
> path: 'C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\PokéBot\data\533791662628143106\team\1.json'

I tried to remove `await` before `mkdir` but it didn't work. I also tried to put the entire jsoning part inside of the mkdir callback, first as a normal function and then with async.

When I tried to add `.then` after `mkdir` I got : cannot read "then" of undefined, plus the ERROR : ENOENT...

PS : jsoning is a library to edit json files, here is their website with the docs : https://jsoning.js.org/

The `teamMember.set` part works better with await before but I tried and it doesn't change the error message.

Please help me, where does this error come from ?

**EDIT** : I was tring to generate json files with mkdir, but it wasn't the thing to do. Here is the working code :

```
      const { mkdir } = require("fs/promises");
      await mkdir(`./data/${member.id}/team`, (err)=> console.log(err));

      // User team
      for(let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
          let teamMember = new jsoning(`./data/${member.id}/team/${i}.json`);
          await teamMember.set(`pokemon`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`nickname`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`shiny`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`hasMultipleForms`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`formList`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`form`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`ability`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`baseStats`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`currentStats`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`evs`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`ivs`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`moves`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`movesPP`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`heldItem`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`currentHps`, "");
          await teamMember.set(`statusEffect`, "");
      }
```

Comment: I want to clarify that the folder with the path `PokéBot\data\533791662628143106` is created before this part of the script is executed and does exist, the code is supposed to create the `team/` folder and the json files inside.

Comment: @Andreas I want my code to create this file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the original callback `fs` module (that "cannot call `then` on `undefined` makes that fairly clear). So your code is continuing and trying to use the directory **before** `mkdir` has created it, because you're not using the `mkdir` callback.

If you want to use promises, use the `fsPromises` module [as described here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system):

ESM:

```
import * as fs from "fs/promises";
```

CJS:

```
const fs = require("fs/promises");
```

Then `await` will pause the loop until the work is done.

If all you're using is `mkdir`, you can also just import that:

ESM:

```
import { mkdir } from "fs/promises";
```

CJS:

```
const { mkdir } = require("fs/promises");
```

Then use `mkdir` instead of `fs.mkdir`.

---

Side note: I don't see a declaration for `i` anywhere. If you don't have one, be sure to declare it.

Comment: Thank you ! I found out that I didn't actually know what was `mkdir` doing, as I tried to generate json files with it... Your answer was helpful because it helped me modify my code : I used the promise mkdir to make the `./data/id/team/` folder before this block of code, then I ran the `for` loop with async jsoning code and it worked.